# How do I count the number of times a date shows up in a list?

Tags: python, csv, counting, arcpy

So I am having an issue. I am trying to create a script that will look at a layer in ArcMap (we use 10.2.2) create a csv file that for the final output will have the technicians name and the number of tracts that they have looked at on a particular day. To do this, I think that I need to create a dictionary that is specific to each technician and has the date as a key and the number of times it comes up as the value.

This is where I am getting stuck. How do I create a dictionary that counts the number of times a date comes up?

I included my code so far and I am at a huge loss of where to go or if I am even on the right tract. Also I am unsure how to make the csv file with all three columns I need (Name, Date, Count).

```
import arcpy, datetime
from arcpy import mapping
from datetime import datetime

# pass layer to script
mxd = mapping.MapDocument("C:\\Users\\eschlueter\\Desktop\\test\\test.mxd")
layers = mapping.ListLayers(mxd)

inLayer = layers[0]
csvfilename = "C:\\Users\\eschlueter\\Desktop\\test\\test1.csv"

# Create the search cursor
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(inLayer)

##define a dictionary of every technician
elizabethtech = {}
unknowntech = {}

##create a counter for each technician's contracts
Elizabethcontract = 0
Unknowncontract = 0

##Define Variables and Iterate through the rows in cursor
desc = arcpy.Describe(inLayer)
fields =  desc.fields
for field in fields:
    for srow in cursor:
        tech = srow.getValue("Technician")
        ModDate = srow.getValue("ModifiedDate")
        if tech == "Elizabeth Schlueter":
            Elizabethcontract = Elizabethcontract + 1
            ESList = []
            ES = {}
            FormDate = ModDate.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
            print FormDate
            ESList.append(FormDate)
            c = ESList.count(FormDate)
            ES[FormDate] = c
            print ES
```

I could really use some help on this one! Thank you guys for helping me in advance!

**UPDATE**

I have been able to create the dictionary using the Counter and the .update method and created a master list of all the technicians as the key and the value being the (date, count). How do I now take this dictionary and print a csv file? I want the file to have the technician name and the date and the count of the dates. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi Elizabeth, welcome to stackoverflow! Your can improve your question by reducing your sample code to the minimum necessary to reproduce your problem. Please read "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" at the help center. Also, take a look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), python programmers are very sensitive  to naming and formating conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Counter class in the collections package.  It's a type of dictionary where the keys will be dates (in your case), and the values will be the accumulated counts of how many times that date occurred.  So for each employee you create a Counter instead of a dictionary.  As you parse the data you collect the new dates for each employee and add them to the Counter (see Counter.update).

```
from collections import Counter
dates = ['5-11-15','5-12-15','5-11-15']
c = Counter()
c.update(dates) 
print(c)
```

This prints:
Counter({'5-11-15': 2, '5-12-15': 1})

Comment: I tried something like that but I don't think I did it right. I ended up with the same entry many times instead of it counting. For example, I would have it print the counter and it would say 5-11-2015 : 1 multiple times. Do you think you can help me out by giving me a sample of the coding? Counters are new to me. :)

Comment: Also, how would I think take the counter dictionary and convert it so I can print a csv with the dates and count and technician's name?

Comment: I added a short code snippet.  I don't know why you can't get it to work - it's pretty simple.  What exactly are the objects you are trying to count?   Are they strings or perhaps some other object that has more complicated behavior?  In order for Counters to work for you, two objects must compare equal when you want them to represent the same date.

Comment: Coubters have the same semantics as dictionaries so you loop through their elements with `items()` (assuming Python 3).  Then you print the keys and values in whatever format you want.